# serial correlation, homocedasticity tests for non linear and non parametric regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

For linear and parametric regression there are multiple tests where variables and residuals are used by means of performing a linear regression function to test serial correlation of regression errors and homocedasticity of regression errors.

My question is about non linear and non parametric regression for prediction or classification such us SVM, NeuralNets, knn, Recursive Partitioning, Adaptive Regression Spline, etc.

In this regard my questions are:

1. As is not linear regression what is the equivalent of OLS assumptions for non linear non parametric regression. Are the consequences of OLS violation in the context of nonlinear and non-parametric regression still valid?
2. How could I test or what tests exist for serial correlation of errors for non linear and non parametric regression which are not derived from visual inspection of a graph and by using error residuals only. (something comes in mind like testing for significant acf or pacf on the residual errors - Unsure if this is OK).
3. How could I test or what tests exist for homocedasticity for non linear and non parametric regression which are not derived from visual inspection of a graph and by using error residuals only. (something comes too mind like homogenity of distances between the residual errors across time).
4. Would it be better to transfor the data into linear by seeking some adequate transformation as to avoid all the non linearity issues mentioned above?

Thank you